# Estimating FFT error

Tags: adc, error, fft

I'm interested in trying to estimate the worst-case error when using a particular DFT implementation (CMSIS) and an ADC and voltage reference with known error bounds.

I think that I can work out the math itself without much issue, but I'm not clear what "worst-case" looks like.

I have a vibrating string with constant fundamental harmonic frequency (like a guitar string) per "pluck" - the frequency can change from pluck to pluck though.  The fundamental frequency should have the highest magnitude by a good margin, so higher-order harmonics and outside noise should not present too much problem.

So if I assume that my ADC is, say, +-2 LSB at 2kSamples/s (using a sample size of 1024 points with a perfect voltage reference), and I look at a simple sine wave of representative frequency, what would the worst case look like?

- Would it be if the ADC alternated between +2 and -2 LSB on each measurement?
- Or maybe it would "throw off" FFT more to have every measurement be +2 LSB for a certain time then all of a sudden be -2 LSB?

Clearly (?) there is some point where you want to ADC measurements to be off by its extremes, otherwise its just a translation of the wave.

- Has anyone seen a resource for figuring out this kind of thing before? Or is it better just to run a few thousand examples and do a statistical analysis to determine likely bounds?

My motivation is to discover if I can know *a priori* if I should go with an ADC of less precision and accuracy, i.e. if a certain ADC is overkill.

Comment: I don't understand what the error that you're worried about is. Error in doing what? Between what and what?

Comment: In actual use, the background noise level, music store HVAC system, power supply fans across the room, etc. can produce more the +-2 LSBs of Gaussian white noise into a high gain mic + 16-bit audio ADC.  Also, single guitar plucks change frequency over the duration of the note, and the fundamental pitch frequency isn't always the strongest spectral peak in a DFT.  So... statistical analysis of data from actual conditions, yes.

Comment: @hotpaw2 Useful, thanks.  Also not an actual guitar string, but a vibrating system where the fundamental should have the largest magnitude (at least I'm fairly sure).  So if this is the case, I'm guessing that devices which are meant to use measurements of fundamental frequencies (some chem lab calibration equipment for instance) don't have particularly accurate error bound specifications?

Comment: @MarcusMüller The error between calculated fundamental from FFT and the actual fundamental?

Comment: ah. Obviously, that is half the FFT bin width.

Comment: @Trivia If you are doing FFT or DFT, there are numerical errors to analyze using numerical methods theory which also takes into consideration the algorithms used. Which I think means you have to write equations, take all of the associated PDEs, etc. This isn't only about looking at the FFT/DFT itself. It also includes ***how*** you perform those calculations (there isn't just one way.) You will find one algorithm "bounds maximum error" while another only "bounds average error," for example. The whole process of applying numerical methods in computing is itself a "field or work."

Comment: For unmodulated spectral peaks surrounded by a low noise floor, interpolation of the DFT results can provide frequency estimates with higher resolution than half the DFT bin width.  Polynomial interpolation is decent. Windowed Sinc even better.  Also, try phase vocoder estimation methods for stationary peaks if you can get DFTs of overlapped data windows.

Comment: @jonk Thanks!  This was actually what I intended to ask, given that I know the FFT implementation, and I'm capable of doing the analysis, is there an "industry" method for making claims about maximum error?  Luckily I'm a mathematician so I've already been able to discover quite a few useful things, but I still can't find a "standard" way of finding a priori estimates.  It does seem that certain methods of varying the ADC output values yields significantly more error than others for this particular implementation, but it's not clear if there is a "worst" way to vary them.

Comment: @MarcusMüller That would account for the error from the transform, not in the ADC output/FFT input.  Think of it this way: say I take 1024 measurements from the ADC and the first measurement from the ADC was off by +2 LSB, and the rest were off by -2 LSB (and that you could know this). Would that yield a different error from the FFT (known implementation) than if the first three were off by +2 and the rest by -2?  Would the magnitude of error (in this case just abs(actual Hz - measured Hz)) increase?  Could we get a worse error by taking a different error pattern from the ADC?

Comment: @TrivialCase I'm glad to hear you are a mathematician! That's a good thing. The techniques I apply when faced with a problem are based on my own creative imagination and the mathematical toolsets I understand well. (You are probably asking in the wrong place as electronics engineers, while good at applied mathematics, are far less likely to be well-grounded in abstract mathematics. And many will prefer to "hunt and peck" and hope they hunted enough.) After reading your comment to Marcus, and then prior comments again, I'm beginning to see better what you are on about.

Comment: @TrivialCase ADC readings are exposed to a variety of errors, some external to the ADC and some internal. Offset error, uncorrelated voltage noise and current noise, correlated voltage and current noise, varying gain error over range, analog sampling error, ADC truncation error, ADC noise, etc. Can you identify which kind of error you are trying to bound? Each as their own characteristics. For example, uncorrelated voltage noise will be Poisson and integrate very closely to a Gaussian shape and you can use that model in analysis. But gain error isn't like that.

Comment: @TrivialCase A sensitivity analysis (which is what I'm gathering you are heading towards -- for reasons I can't say I follow yet) to various kinds of actual errors that engineers experience in practical designs, would be an "interesting to do." It may be that someone has done it for each type of error taken individually. As a side-bar, I'd recommend that you write to Grant Sanderson and see if you can interest him in writing back. He has a public face on youtube as 3blue1brown. Worth a shot. I think, at the very least, he may have some considerations to offer you.

Comment: @TrivialCase However, if all you care about is simply offsetting the data, then all you are doing is affecting the \$n=0\$ case of the FFT. But even there, you may want to analyze the interesting issue of a moving offset in the analog domain as it affects and is sampled by an ADC and then truncated and affects the FFT results. Actually, that should not be too hard to analyze and get some bounds on.... But I'd need to think a little more on that, if that's where you are headed.

Comment: @jonk Yes, I was thinking of a sensitivity analysis where we are trying to find the "worst" possible output of the ADC (within its spec) for this particular DFT algorithm.  What would "worst" mean here?  I was interested initially because if you could find this, then you would know whether you could go for, say, a 12-bit ADC with such and such error specs vs 16-bit ADC with some other error specs if you wanted to measure the fundamental of a signal to within some margin of error (e.g. +- 0.003Hz, given it must lay between 800Hz and 1200Hz).

Comment: @jonk Also, now that we are closing in on identifying what I intended to ask, is there some way I could edit the question to make more sense?

Comment: @TrivialCase This is something I'd probably say requires some "sit-down" time. A priori, we know you are talking about an FFT (which is a particular collection of approaches towards a computationally efficient transform.) The transform itself, sans efficiency, is pure mathematics and has its own beautiful symmetries about which I'd like to think, first. The efficiency approach used in FFTs modifies that pure machinery in a way I'd need to first visualize better than I have. Following that, I'd need to think about what the error sources "look like" to a mathematician....

Comment: @TrivialCase and what kinds of symmetries a mathematician may find there. It seems like something one could spend a week or two on, just allowing the imagination to fly. But it appears to me to be something that promises some new and interesting insights. You may be lucky to have an opportunity to pursue this. The parts of the imagery in my mind that I do have firmly in place is already feeling attractive to follow. I wish I could draw it all out for you.... but it would take time and I probably would need to animate it.

Comment: @TrivialCase I kind of know how I'd re-write the question. But by the time I got done with that, it absolutely would have no place here at all. It would be better sent over the the mathematics group. And even there, the last time I asked a question it took like 4 years for someone who had the right insights to finally share them with me. So I can't say I recommend that, either. I think you really need to engage a theoretical/abstract mathematician. They are cheap. (One that teaches me Coxeter polytropes and Lie Groups is a string theorist working at the pinnacle of the field and makes $3k/yr.)